# How to unhighlight row in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created a DataGridView with different columns.

I have kept selection feature by which one can get selected row by a button click and prompt an error when the row is not selected on button click.

I see that the first row in table is always selected.

Is there a way such that the row can appear unselected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

Or

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = Nothing;
```

Or

```
dataGridView1.Rows[Index].Selected = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

try [ClearSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxdf3ekh(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `DataGridView`

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

It should clear the current selection.

Comment: If you don't want even the first row/cell to appear selected, you can set the CurrentCell property to null, which will temporarily hide the focus rectangle until the control receives focus again.